# Creating probabilistic model to estimate probable radiosonde landing zones from predictions

Tags: machine-learning, probability, bayesian, conditional-probability

First of all I'd like to say that I'm new to statistics and machine learning, however I have basic understanding of Bayes' theorem and basic statistics and probability.

My problem is as follows: I have a large dataset containing value pairs. First of them is predicted landing point of meteorogical radiosonde, second value is the actual point where the radiosonde landed, both as geographic coordinates. I wanted to create a probabilistic model that would enable me to map out the most probable zones where a radiosonde is expected to land based on single input, which would be the predicted landing point of said radiosonde. I was thinking of using multivariate normal distribution and writing iterative algorithm, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach, and if it is, I'm not sure what my Sigma would be in this case. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It helps to use as much knowledge that you have about the problem. Geographical coordinates are usually 2D, longitude and latitude.

If you are interested in the "spread" between predicted and actual landing site, you could take the total distance, e.g. the radius or calculate both differences in longitude and latitude. If you do this for all data points you have, you will have a distribution of values. This distribution is then the input to anything else you are doing. You can calculate all kinds of moments and central moments (mean, standard deviation, etc.) from this or these distribution/s.

If you only have these the input values, the the dimension is also two. In case there is no significant difference between either direction of deviation, you actually have a univariate distribution. Your result is then a kind of shooting target - like heat map, which is also the best predictor for future deviations -- unless there is something more.

Comment: In my case the direction matters as well. By having predicted coordinates and actual coordinates (2D), I'd like to create a model which not only predicts the spread in terms of uniform circle around the predicted point, but a model that  basing on the data I have predicts how likely is the radiosonde to land e.g. to the north, or to the east of the predicted point

Comment: @user747644 This doesn't change the basic procedure. But still, if you only have the predicted coordinates, then there is nothing else to build anything on. You could try to look at the covariances and see if there are certain trends depending on the actually predicted values. But still, if the dimension of your input space is equal to the dimension of your output space, there is little to go on.